# How to I authenticate with a ISA proxy from my application seamlessly?

Tags: c++, qt, proxy

I am trying to us Qt to access a website and download updates, the problem is that one install base is using a Microsoft ISA proxy server which requires authentication.

Qt gives me a function to supply a username and password:
http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#proxyAuthenticationRequired

However other applications do this without asking the user for details.  How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of proxy are you running? See

http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qnetworkproxy.html

to find what proxies Qt support.

Comment: It is a Microsoft ISA HTTP proxy with authentication, however the QAuthenticate object cannot get the current logged on users credentials to pass to the proxy server.  In .NET the WebProxy object has a UseDefaultCredentials parameter which does not require the application to supply a username and password.